# How to login without showing a login button on my personal blog

Tags: google-app-engine, blog-engine

I decided to write a personal blog engine on Google App Engine.

But I really do not like the idea of adding a login button somewhere. How can I still do admin things, i,e, post an article, delete a comment and etc, without a login button?

One ugly solution may be not showing the login button but still proviing the login url which  you can type in manually to login. There is not much difference. I don't like this one.

Any one know some other ways around this? I've seen many blogs without the login button, how do they implement this?

UPDATE:

One offline solution may be using the remote_api provided by App Engine, that is somewhat applicable and I'm considering using it. But you always need the App Engine Toolkit to do it. So it might not be as portable as an online version in which case every thing you need is just a modern and the network connection.

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict access to a specific resource of your application by using the `login` option in `app.yaml` handler definition:

```
- url: /admin
  login: admin
  script: admin.app
```

Then using the [Users API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/adminusers) you can easily check on your main page if the current user in is an admin, and decide to show or not a link to this protected resource:

```
if users.is_current_user_admin():
   # render link to /admin
```

Comment: To detect the kind of user, you must login first.